# Setting property reference for a bean programmatically

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

Right now i am using the following bean entry

```
<bean id="Service" >
    <property name="target">
            <bean class="someClass" lazy-init="false">
                <property name="SessionFactory1"><ref bean="SessionFactory1"/></property>
                <property name="SessionFactory2"><ref bean="SessionFactory2"/></property>
                <property name="SessionFactory3"><ref bean="SessionFactory3"/></property>
           </bean>
        </property>

</bean>
```

Now the requirement is to first check which all session factories have an active datasource and include those only in the above bean definition. So that the application does not break if we try to initialize a session factory with inactive datasource.

sessionfactory initialization will be take care by using seperate config xml for session factories and loading only the ones with active datasources.

Please help on how can this be achieved.

Comment: I tried to follow the approach suggested by you. It does allow me to catch the exception if something goes wrong in configuration.  But, was still not able to figure out how can I programmatically set the bean properties using afterPropertiesSet. Or continue with using just the sessionfactories which configured correctly. I am very new to springs. So, please dont mind the stupid doubts

Comment: Also, as can be seen from my question. The properties I am trying to add have reference to session factories amd are not key values pairs of String

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring `InitializingBean` interface, which makes you implement an `afterPropertiesSet()` method. This method will be executed after Spring instantiates your class, and you could check if your session factories are available or not.

> InitializingBean: Interface to be implemented by beans that need to react once all their properties have been set by a BeanFactory: for example, to perform custom initialization, or merely to check that all mandatory properties have been set.

link: [Spring InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)